# Vista: file browse/upload dialog crashes browser and Photoshop

Tags: windows-vista, upload, dialog

Situation: Using a web browser, the user is trying to upload files to a website. Each time a file is selected, the browser crashes. Every time the browser prompts to Select A File for upload.

The same behaviour occurs when the user tries to Save For Web in Adobe Photoshop.

Question: are there any ideas why the Browse dialog would cause an application to crash?.

Comment: any clues on how you resolved your crash issues?

Comment: Anything in the event logs? Is there a particular message you get when things crash?

Answer (score 1):

The file open/save dialog is handled by Windows Explorer, that's why you see the issue in different applications.

This behavior is very often caused by a bad shell exstension. They're often installed by programs like Adobe Photoshop, codec packs and other applications.

There is a good tool from sysinternals called autoruns which you can find here http://live.sysinternals.com/autoruns.exe. Run that tool, wait for it to do it's initial scan, go to Options and mark **Hide Microsoft and Windows entries** and **Verify code signatures** hit **F5** and wait for it to scan once more.
Select the **Explorer** tab and deselect the items you find in the list, reboot and see if it solves your problem.